# For a Poisson Process with rate $\lambda$ and arrivals $S_i$, how to find $E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(t-S_i)\right]$ if I know conditional expectations?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Suppose that travelers arrive to a train station according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. If a train departs at time $t$, we may find the expected sum of the waiting times of travelers arriving in the time interval $(0,t)$. In other words, we can find:

$$
E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(t-S_i)\right]
$$

where $S_i$ is the arrival time of the $i$th traveler.

I know that the standard way to handle this is by conditioning. I am able to use the property of a Poisson Process being related to Uniform Order Statistics to obtain:

$$
E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(t-S_i) \mid N(t) = n\right] = \frac{nt}{2}
$$

However, given this result, how can I formally show that:

$$
E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(t-S_i) \right] = \frac{t}{2}E[N(t)] = \lambda \frac{t^2}{2}
$$?

It looks like the law of conditional expectations is at play, but I cannot obtain the right form, as it looks like taking expectations to the second equation results in:

$$
E\left[E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(t-S_i) \mid N(t) = n\right]\right] = E\left[\frac{nt}{2}\right] = \frac{nt}{2}
$$

which is not what we want as the random variable $N(t)$ doesn't appear. How can we get the right form? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using
$$
E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(t-S_i) \mid N(t) = n\right] = \frac{nt}{2},
$$
You can compute
$$
E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(t-S_i)\right] = 
\sum_{n\geq 0} E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(t-S_i) \mid N(t) = n\right] \times P[N(t)=n],
$$
using the Poisson distribution.

Comment: My book uses the argument $E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(t-S_i) \right] = \frac{t}{2}E[N(t)] = \lambda \frac{t^2}{2}$. Can this relation be obtained from what you have above? In other words, can I obtain the $E[N(t)]$ by itself? Thanks!